# AWS DynamoDB and Storing User Data with Transactional Data in one table

Tags: database, postgresql, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, rdbms

I am looking at ways to store user data alongside transactional data like orders and invoices. Normally, I would use a relational database like postgresql, but I wanted to know if it would be a good idea to store the user data along with their transactional data in one noSQL table like DynamoDB?

I would assume if you did that you would structure your data to either use objects or arrays to store the orders or invoices but I'm not sure if that is the best was to go about it.

**EDIT**

So after doing some more research and trying understand how to fit everything into a single table design I found this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItemCollections.html) in the AWS documentation. I decided to organise my data into collections using a combinaton of the primary key and the sort key. The sort key is used to determine collections (i.e., orders, customer-data, etc). This solution is perfect for my use case because I can keep all the user data (including transactions like orders) in one dynamodb table.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In short, don't do that. DynamoDB is a great tool, but you need to understand it first. It's not just a no-sql, it's also a distributed one. It gives great performance, scalability and pricing. But modeling is trickier. You can not build requests as you please, those has to be taken into consideration when you design your model. Read about queries vs scans and global vs local indexes. When you get that you might try reading about Single Table Design. It should give you an idea about the limitations of the DynamoDB.